# knowing when a sqlalchemy filter found something or not

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I was trying to figure out how to figure out if something was found by my sqlalchemy filter call to know if I should iterate over the results or not.

The only other way I can figure out how to do this is calling first:

```
ld = ld=LunchDay.query.filter(and_(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp == datetime.date.today()), LunchDay.status==1)).first()
```

then if ld is None nothing was found.  But if that is the case, I cannot iterate over all what was found so I have to do the call again:

```
ld = ld=LunchDay.query.filter(and_(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp == datetime.date.today()), LunchDay.status==1))
```

I thought there has to be a better way, I thought the filter throws an exception if nothing is found so I did try this (in the shell):

```
try:
    ld=LunchDay.query.filter(and_(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp == datetime.date.today()), LunchDay.status==1))
    #do stuff with results
except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound:
    #SHOW THE ERROR
```

but it never seems to error out when I know nothing was returned?  Is my logic totally messed up on this?
Is the 'double check' the preferred way?  or am I not using the exception right?

Comment: Instead of using `.first()`, you can turn your results into a list with `.all()`, and then test if the list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use count, e.g.

```
count = LunchDay.query.filter(and_(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp == datetime.date.today()), LunchDay.status==1)).count()

if count:
  # do stuff
```

or you can iterate using .all():

```
lds =LunchDay.query.filter(and_(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp == datetime.date.today()), LunchDay.status==1)).all()
for ld in lds:
  # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    ld = LunchDay.query.filter(and_(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp == datetime.date.today()), LunchDay.status==1)).all()

    if ld:
       for row in ld:
           // your code
```